# How do I read FireWire (IEEE 1394) format data from a USB?

Tags: linux, windows, usb, camera, firewire

I am trying to read some tapes from my camcorder which exports data in the FireWire (IEEE 1394 format. However, I don't have a FireWire (IEEE 1394 port on my computer, so I got a converter cable from FireWire (IEEE 1394 to USB. However, Windows MovieMaker can't seem to find the camcorder when I tell it to import from a device.

Is there a method that will read the FireWire (IEEE 1394 video input from a USB port
(i.e., and write it to a file)?

I have access to Windows and Ubuntu, and can probably borrow someone's Mac if necessary.

Comment: Exactly what sort of converter cable did you get? This combination makes very little sense.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0113LZ3BK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the product page (and especially the reviews), your cable seems to be a passive adapter which just connects USB pins straight to FireWire pins. This doesn't make any sense, as the two use completely different communication protocols.

The only way that could *possibly* work if the device *already* had the ability to switch between FireWire and USB, which would be possible, but probably somewhat rare. (Like those USB mice with "PS/2 adapters.") If your camcorder didn't recognize the connection, then it's probably FireWire-only and won't work with passive converters.

(I'm not sure if even *active* USB2-to-FireWire adapters can work properly, due to DMA in FireWire being controlled by the device...)

Instead, you'll need a full PCI card with FireWire ports, or a Thunderbolt-to-FireWire adapter.

Comment: Thanks, so I should buy a cable that has a card?

Comment: What would you connect such a cable to?... If you have a desktop PC, get [one of these](https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=pcie+firewire) and a regular FireWire cable.